# Add year (multiple different years) in cells that have only day and month (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet as follows in column B:

```
10/11
27/10
05/05
01/01
24/12
11/07
03/03
27/11
15/10
```

The top ones are always from the year that we are, in this example it's 2019, but according to what goes back to 24/12 means that we are going to December 2018, going down a little bit and getting to 27/11 means that we are going to November 2017.

I would like to know if there is any formula that could make this distinction in the year and add it in Column A, because the data I import from always updates and comes with only day and month.

**Expected Result:**

```
2019   10/11
2019   27/10
2019   05/05
2019   01/01
2018   24/12
2018   11/07
2018   03/03
2017   27/11
2017   15/10
```

Link to Spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tXxPdZMjkqIUPKlJt9j8fBdgMfRTH6rU1BeGpHW-m6Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i do believe this kind of question should go to [webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can compare the current row month and previous row month, if more greater then decreased previous row year by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your link spread sheet, I put this in cell A1:

```
=year(B1)
```

in A2 I put:

```
=if(right(B2,2)>right(B1,2),A1-1,A1)
```

all other cells in column A until last row of data, I copy from A2, then I get the results:

```
2018    29/12
2017    30/12
2016    26/12
```